# how to host a site with https using iis

Tags: c#, iis

I have a site in IIS and I wan't it to be hosted in as HTTPS with a domain name.
I tried it by adding https in bindings with ssl certificate. When I browse my site I get "Your connection is not private" error.

Comment: Is it a self-signed certificate, or one from a trusted CA?

Comment: Self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

This site will guide you how to generate and install a free certificate on your server: https://www.sslforfree.com

Here you have a big explanation why the error occurs (maybe because it is a self-signed certificate, and browser does not trust it): http://www.zerodollartips.com/your-connection-is-not-private-chrome

Comment: Is it possible to generate the ssl using IIS in which I have hosted my application